# WP_Query not ordered correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, shortcode

I have a custom post type `cota` where all data is displayed in a `<table>` in my site. I need to order this table by:

- `administradora` - some kind of "category" that the user specifies. Ordered ASC (a-z);
- `valor` - The price of the `cota`. Each `cota` has a price. Ordered DESC (9 - 0) ;

**The problem** : It's already ordered by `administradora`, but not correctly ordered by `valor`.

Example: The order by `valor` displays first a `cota` with US$9.000,00 and then another `cota` with US$1.000.000,00. It's wrong. The one million dollar `cota` should come first, and then the nine thousand  dollars `cota`.

[Here's an image that shows better the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncjbs.jpg)

**Code for ordering the `cota`:**

```
      $query = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'cota',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'tax_query' => array(
          array(
              'taxonomy' => 'tipo',
              'field'    => 'slug',
              'terms'    => $atts['tipo'],
          ),
      ),
      'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
      'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'valor_clause' => array(
          'key' => 'valor',
          'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        'adm_clause' => array(
          'key' => 'administradora',
          'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        )
      ),
      'orderby' => array(
        'adm_clause' => 'ASC',
        'valor_clause' => 'DESC'
      )
    )
  );
```

**EDIT 1**: After some research, i found out that wordpress saves all its data as `longtext` in the database. But still cannot solve the problem.

I can provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'cota',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'tipo',
          'field'    => 'id',
          'terms'    => $atts['tipo'],
      ),
  ),
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'valor_clause' => array(
      'key' => 'valor',
      'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    ),
    'adm_clause' => array(
      'key' => 'administradora',
      'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    )
  ),
  'orderby' => array(
    'adm_clause' => 'ASC',
    'valor_clause' => 'DESC'
  )
)
);
```

Comment: Didn't work. If i change the `field` from `slug` to `id`, the data is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

The following code should work:

```
      $query = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'cota',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'tax_query' => array(
          array(
              'taxonomy' => 'tipo',
              'field'    => 'slug',
              'terms'    => $atts['tipo'],
          ),
      ),
      'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'credito_clause' => array(
          'key' => "valor",
          'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
          'type' => 'DECIMAL',
          'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        'adm_clause' => array(
          'key' => 'administradora',
          'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        )
      ),
      'orderby' => array(
        'adm_clause' => 'ASC',
        'credito_clause' => 'DESC'
      )
    )
  );
```